# If we heat a 1Ly long copper stick through all its length to expand 1% what will be the relative speed of its two ends?

Tags: temperature, speed-of-light, acoustics, material-science

If we heat a 1Ly long copper stick through all its length to expand 1% what will be the relative speed of its two ends? If we, for example, heat up a copper stick by 600°C it will expand 1% so my question is, I think, simple: what should be the difference in speed of the two ends if the rise in temperature is done in let say 10 seconds?

Comment: The structural phase transition happens locally so why would the length of the stick matter?

Answer (score 1):

The wire will have a length of 1.01 ly only in its new thermal equilibrium state, which takes in principle an infinite long time.
Therefore the time which is needed to rise the temperature does not really matter and the expansion will take definitely longer than those 10s.
What will always hold is that the relative speed between the ends of the wire won't be faster than the speed of light.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the question. It's not specified that the object is at thermal equilibrium, only that 600°C heating occurs in 10 seconds. And the question is about the relative speed of the ends. Please consider revising to address the relevant aspects.

Comment: While the wire still expands it is clearly not in a equilibrium state. The relative speed would be a function of time and I think with the given information it is not possible to tell quantitatively. What I pointed out above is that you can not assume that in those 10s the wire will expand by the total of 1% and therefore a simple calculation with the assumption that the ends will move by 0.01 ly relativ to each other in 10 seconds is false. (This would lead to a result where the ends would be faster than light)